# How to cut decimal off without rounding in C

Tags: c, rounding

How do I cut off decimal places in C without rounding?

For example if the number is `4.48`

it will just show `4.4`

`%.1f` rounds to `4.5`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a simple way:

```
printf("%.1f",trunc(x*10.0)/10.0);
```

Comment: Note: Overflow possible with `x*10.0`.

Comment: To generalize this answer, if you want approximation of "n" decimal digits without round-off, multiply and divide in the above fashion with 10 ^ "n".

Answer (score 14):

You can (ab)use the fact that integer division truncates and doesn't round:

```
float original = 4.48;

int tmp = original * 10; // 44.8 truncated to 44

float truncated = tmp / 10.0; // 4.4
```

Comment: To avoid `int` conversion overflow, use `trunc*()` as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12764022/2410359).  Still may have edge issues.

Comment: Doesn't this new floating point division introduce rounding errors?

Answer (score 3):

If your compiler supports C99, you should be able to use [`trunc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/trunc) and friends:

```
float f = 4.56f;
f = truncf(f * 10.0) / 10.0;
```

Comment: Note that `10.0` is a `double` here and so the `*` and `/` are performed at least to `double` precision`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
double d = 4.48;
d *= 10.;
int i = d;
d = (double) i / 10.;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
float myval = 4.48;
float tr = ((int)(myval*10)) / 10.0;
```

Answer (score -3):

I see that you're using Format Specifiers and it's one that I'm familiar with from a scripting language. If the one you're using works, then I'd assume the rest of these work too.

The language I am thinking of uses the same specifier to provide several functionalities.

if you use "%0.4f" 3.14159 becomes ".1415"

if you use "%2.1f" then it becomes "03.1"

if you use "%1.2f you'll get "3.14"

Comment: This does not solve the OP's problem of rounding, which the OP wanted to avoid.