# How to show only 1 digit in a float correctly?

Tags: c, floating-point

If I have a float number- 28.274309, 
and I want to show only 1 digit after the dot, I use %.1f. 
But then the result is 28.3. 
How do I make it 28.2 and not 28.3?

Comment: Why do you want 28.2 when 28.3  is closer to the true value?

Comment: Because its for an assignment i do and they asked for 28.2... weird, but how do i do it correctly?

Comment: `trunc(x*10.0)/10.0;`  [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12764022/2410359)

Comment: @chux: That does not work. For example, if `x` is 1.79999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875, the desired result would be 1.7 in decimal, and nearly that in binary. But `x*10.0` produces exactly 18, `trunc(x*10.0)` produces 18, and `trunc(x*10.0)/10.0` produces 1.8000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Perhaps it may not work for a select case, yet `1.7999999999999998223...` is not a `float` value and OP's post is about `float`.  I too am looking for a `float` counter example.  `trunc(x*10.0)/10.0;` is taking advantage of the wider precision math of `double`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Of course OP use of "float" could be taken as any _floating point_ type.  My comment works `float`.  - No counter example yet.

Comment: @chux multiplying the conversion to `double` of a `float` by `10.0` is exact (they respectively use 24 and 3 bits of significand, so the product needs 27 to be represented), making the `trunc(x*10.0)` part of your method correct. I would compose the output from that integer to be on the safe side.