# reduce decimal places in C without rounding

Tags: c, rounding

I'm using this code and in the situation where the user inputs 78.5 tax gets rounded from 5.495 to 5.50 I want it to simply cutout anything after the second decimal place without rounding.

```
#include "cs50.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float charge = get_float("Enter the charge for food: ");
    float tip = charge/100 * 18;
    printf("Tip: $%.2f\n", tip);
    float tax = charge/100 * 7;
    printf("Tax: $%.2f\n", tax);
    float total = charge + tip + tax;
    printf("Total: $%.2f", total);
}
```

I tried using .f2 but it seems to be rounding the number still as referenced in [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764009/how-to-cut-decimal-off-without-rounding-in-c). im also using online GDB if this changes anything.

Comment: @might be andrew, `5.495` is not a representable number as a `float` nor `double`.  Try `printf("%.17g\n", 5.495);` to see what the real number is and then let us know what output you expect from that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is an efficient way to do this but the simplest method I can think of is: to multiply the number by 1000, remove the last digit, and divide it by 1000 again. Something like this:

```
float x = 5.495;
int y = (int)(x * 1000); // 5495
y -= y % 10; // 5495 - 5 = 5490
x = y / 1000.0; // 5.49
```

Alternatively, you could achieve this via casting to an integer.

```
float x = 5.495;
int y = (int)(x * 100); // 549
x = (float)y / 100; // 5.49
```

This way seems to be better.

Comment: You can't use `%` with `float`. Rejected by compiler.

Comment: @WeatherVane fixed by casting to integer

Comment: Or multiply by 100, use [`truncf()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.12.9.8), and divide by 100.  That's part of the standard C library — it's the `float` variant of the `trunc()` function for `double` values.  `x = truncf(100.0F * x) / 100.0F;`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that is very close to the second code piece